# made a mistake: document collection is an embedded function

Tags: mongodb

so, I managed to create a document collection called ***version*** ...

starting up the mongo shell, I have this

```
> show collections
customer
system.indexes
version
```

**db.customer.find()** gives me a list of my customer data
**db.version.find()** gives a syntax error

```
2015-11-19T22:12:59.598+0000 TypeError: Object function (){
    return this.serverBuildInfo().version;
} has no method 'find'
```

and **db.version()** gives

```
> db.version()
2.6.6
```

so I am assuming that **version** is a function in mongo.

To come to the question I need to ask :

*how can I get the data of this collection from the mongo shell ? Or can I rename the collection ?*

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access that collection via:

```javascript
> db.getCollection('version')
```

and rename it via:

```javascript
> db.getCollection('version').renameCollection('mynewname')
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this in your scenario, but you can try using the Mongo admin command [renameCollection](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/command/renameCollection/#dbcmd.renameCollection).

```
use admin
db.runCommand( { renameCollection: "test.version", to: "test.foo" } )
```

Then once the collection is off the reserved name you can do what you want with the new colection.